# How can i export variables from function in a class?

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, telegram-bot

I have a class SceneGenerator in my Telegram bot. This class generate some scenes for user interaction and it get age from user. Question is how i can export variable `currAge` to another class or file? For example i want to add variable value into database.

Class SceneGenerator

```
class ScenesGenerator {
  GenAgeScene() {
    const age = new Scene('age')
    age.enter((ctx) => ctx.reply('Input you age'))

    age.on('text', async (ctx) => {
      const currAge = Number(ctx.message.text)
      if (currAge && currAge > 0) {
        await ctx.reply('Great!')
      }
    })

    return age
  }
}

module.exports = ScenesGenerator
```

Answer (score -1):

```
you can use getter and setters to export the variable to another file or another class

class ScenesGenerator {
  constructor(){
    this.age = 0
  }
  ageGetter(){ // getter for the age
   return this.age
  }
  ageSetter(val){ // sets the val to age
  this.age = val
  }
  GenAgeScene() {
     this.ageSetter(new Scene('age'))
     this.age.enter((ctx) => ctx.reply('Input you age'))

    this.age.on('text', async (ctx) => {
      const currAge = Number(ctx.message.text)
      if (currAge && currAge > 0) {
        await ctx.reply('Great!')
      }
    })

    return this.age
  }
}

module.exports = ScenesGenerator
```

you can import the class in another file and create the object of that class
, then you can get the age value by calling ageGetter function

```
const sceneGen= new ScenesGenerator()
console.log(sceneGen.ageGetter()// return the val for age
```

)

Comment: What do getters and setters do that just `sceneGen.age` doesn't?

Comment: Thank you but i cannot use setters or getters because of framework that i use.